# A function returning all keys or values of an object as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, key-value

I need to create a `getObjectData()` function, that returns an array of all keys or values of an object depending on the argument.

If the string `values` is passed as the second argument, it returns the values of the object (obj) and if the string `keys` is passed, it must return the keys.

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'Bill',
    surname: 'Bradley',
    age: 27
};

var pet = {
    animal: 'Dog',
    breed: 'Terrier',
    colour: 'Brown"
};
```

Comment: Second argument? What should be the first argument then?

Comment: please provide us with the code you're talking about.

Comment: Did you actually attempt to write something? Any code to show?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need this function.

[image]

Use `Object.keys` to retrieve keys, and `Object.values` for values. The latter is not universally supported yet, but a polyfill is easy:

```
Object.values = Object.values || (o => Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k]));
```

[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var person = { firstName: 'Bill', surname: 'Bradley', age: 27 }; 
var pet = { animal: 'Dog', breed: 'Terrier', colour: 'Brown' };

function keysOrValues(o, str) {
    switch(str) {
        case 'keys':
          return Object.keys(o);
         case 'values':
          return Object.values(o);
    }
}

console.log(keysOrValues(person, 'keys'));
console.log(keysOrValues(person, 'values'));
```

You may need to polyfill `Object.values`.

Comment: `Object[str](o)`... but really, who needs such a function?

Comment: victoria does!!